# Replacing [ and ] with <b> and <b>

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to convert [ and ] to <b> and </b>

string

```
  $str="I don't [wanna] be a bus [driver] all my [life]";
```

I want this output

```
I don't <b>wanna</b> be a bus <b>driver</b> all my <b>life</b>
```

any word inside [] should be **bold**

So far, This is my code:

```
     $str="I don't [wanna] be a bus [driver] all my [life]";
   echo preg_replace("#[]#","<b></b>",$str);
```

But it doesnt work, it returns the string as it is

```
  I don't [wanna] be a bus [driver] all my [life]
```

Any idea? thanks

Comment: Heck, you could use a simple str_replace() for this: `echo str_replace(['[', ']'], ['<b>', '</b>'], $str);`

Comment: Your problem is that `[` and `]` have special meaning in regular expressions, so they need escaping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $str="I don't [wanna] be a bus [driver] all my [life]";
 $pattern=array();
 $pattern[0]="/\[/";
 $pattern[1]="/\]/";
 $replacement=array();
 $replacement[0]="<b>";
  $replacement[1]="</b>";
  echo preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$str);
```

See this in action  **[here](https://eval.in/300267)**

Answer (score 4):

As stated, the problem doesn't require regular expressions:

```
print strtr($str, [
    '[' => '<b>',
    ']' => '</b>',
]);
```

If you still want regexes, it goes like this:

```
print preg_replace(
    '~\[(.+?)\]~',
    "<b>$1</b>",
    $str);
```

Brackets are escaped, because they have a special meaning in regexes. In the replacement string, `$1` denotes the first captured group `(.+)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one single preg_replace.

You can test it here https://regex101.com/r/sZ6tJ7/1

And see the generated PHP code for it :

```
$re = "/(\\[)([^\\]]*)(\\])/"; 
$str = "I don't [wanna] be a bus [driver] all my [life]"; 
$subst = "<b>$2</b>"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str="I don't [wanna] be a bus [driver] all my [life]";
$pattern=array("/\[/","/\]/");
$replacement=array("<b>","</b>");
echo $output = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$str);
```